# htaccess rewrite with double rules (with version)

Tags: .htaccess, version, double, url-rewriting, rule

I hope a htaccess script voodoo can help me here!

I'm trying to get a htaccess script working using two rules.

I was using a first rule to use folders for different versions, which was great:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=VERSION:020]
RewriteRule ^versions/(.*)$ versions/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ versions/%{ENV:VERSION}/$1 [L]
```

Then I had a structure that take:

```
http://domain.com/
http://domain.com/th?=1
http://domain.com/myfolder/
http://domain.com/myfile.html
```

and send the user to the version that set in the htaccess:

```
http://domain.com/versions/020/
http://domain.com/versions/020/th?=1
http://domain.com/versions/020/myfolder/
http://domain.com/versions/020/myfile.html
```

All working.

But I'd like to add a second rule but I can't get it working with the first rule

I'd like to get these URL:

```
http://domain.com/th/1
http://domain.com/th/12
```

and send the user to:

```
http://domain.com/?th=1
http://domain.com/?th=12
```

and by extension of the first rule:

```
http://domain.com/versions/020/?th=1
http://domain.com/versions/020/?th=12
```

I tried to add:

```
RewriteRule ^th/([0-9]+)/$ http://domain.com/versions/%{ENV:VERSION}/?th=$1
```

But that works only without the first rule (I also can't make it working without the domain name strangely).

How can make this 2 rules working together? Any hint on that?

Cheers.

Romu